# How can i understand it java classes and objects better?

Tags: java, class, oop, object

I am having hard time to understand classes and objects better. I am keep searching to read something or watch new videos, in case someone explain better.

For example, i want to build a car.So i make a class(blueprint) car.

```
public class Car{



}
```

My car want to be a BMW, so the next thing i need to create is a object?

```
Car bmw = new Car();
```

I understand(maybe) that there are many kind of Cars, so i need one class Car, and later i will create new objects with different kind of cars? BMW, Ferrari etc.

But i don't understand the meaning of instance of a class? What does it means? And what happen with this line?

```
Car bmw = new Car();
```

How can different type of car have different properties? 
The methods(action), will be the same, like, drive, stop, turn.

And about Constructors, when i create constructor, is this constructor will be the same of all objects created?

Comment: Read about inheritance. If you want `bmw` to have new properties, make a new `Bmw` class ... `class BMW extends Car { } `

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J3a_OOPBasics.html) helps you to understand OOP better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find millions of tutorial online about Object Oriented Programming, and it's quite a long topic to be answered on SO. I'll just try to say a few words about your example.

Think about a class like a sort of "custom type" for your variables, like an `int` or `double`. You can define what a car is by writing class definition (the "blueprint", as you called it).
This definition will hold basically 2 things:

- the car *properties*, such as the color, number of seats and so
- the car *methods*, which are basically functions that "live" with any car and operate on every *isntance* of a car

In your example this is the car *definition*:

```
public class Car {

}
```

With this you just defined the "type" `Car`, which doesn't have any properties nor methods. For the sake of the example let's add something:

```
public class Car {
    private String color;

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

This is obviously extremely simple. I won't go over the keywords `public` and `private` I used here. For that read about [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) (which is an important aspect of OOP anyway)

Now we have a Car "type" which has a `color` property and a `getColor()` method. Note that `getColor()` is a function that has access to the Car property.

Once you have *defined* the class you still have no actual car "object" (or variable) in your code. Like any other type, you will have to create some car *instances* in your code and assign that instance to a variable to make use of the definition you just gave.

You do this with the `new` operator. In your example the line

```
Car myCar = new Car();
```

creates a new variable `myCar` which holds a reference to a Car *instance*. Again, there's a lot going on here, read about OOP in Java to understand about constructors. If you know something about C/C++ maybe you can read about pointers, references and dynamic memory too, but otherwise leave those for later.

The above line doesn't go inside the class definition (not tipically anyway), it will be part of your main function.

Now you can do something like this (still in your main):

```
myCar.setColor("Red");
String color = myCar.getColor();

System.out.println("the color of my car is: " + color);
// the output on the console will be:
// the color of my car is: Red
```

what we did is set the color *property* of the `Car` *instance* (assigned to the `myCar` *variable*) through its `setColor()` *method*, and retrieve it back using the other `getColor()` *method*.

To understand the importance of instances try this:

```
Car myCar1 = new Car();
Car myCar2 = new Car();

myCar1.setColor("Red");
myCar2.setColor("White");

System.out.println("color of the car 1: " + myCar1.getColor());
System.out.println("color of the car 2: " + myCar2.getColor());
```

The output will be:

```
color of the car 1: Red
color of the car 2: White
```

This stress the fact that you created 2 **different** instances of the `Car` "type" that have *the same properties and methods* (from here the "blueprint" term), but the two instances "live" indipendently from each other.

In the end a `class` gives you a way to build complex objects and define the operations (the methods) that the rest of the code is allowed to do with them (this is also called interface). For such a small example this may seem too much work, but in complex programs it's a very very **very** good thing to do

I will stop here, hope this gave you a better idea of what a class is. Keep studying and, most important, practicing and experimenting. It will be more and more clear when you use it.